# Realize instances node clears the curve tilt

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

When I try to put a `Realize Instances` node before the `Curve to Mesh` node it clears the tilt of the instances. Is there a way around this without having to put the `Curve to Mesh` node before the `Realize Instances` node?

[image]

**Explanation on why I want this:**

The reason is because for my capture attribute which calculates the radius of the curve to work I need to realize my instances before the `Curve to Mesh` hence the tilt problem.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us the Blender version you are using. I just tested it and for me it changes nothing in my example.

Comment: Could you please just explain to us what reason it is that you are using a `Quadratic Bezier` here? To be honest, I am not quite clear what the end result should be. Could you possibly sketch it out? ...because I think that you could build this much easier.

Comment: @quellnform hi sorry I just uploaded another blender version which is more relevant. the reason I converted the curve to mesh after instancing instead of instancing the plane was because I wanted to adjust the curves after instancing using the set position node after the realise instances node and still have the tilt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reading I think I understood it:

[image]

You would simply have to capture the rotation on the *X-axis* with the node `Capture Attribute` on the *Instance-Domain*, and feed this value after the node `Realize Instances` into the node `Set Curve Tilt`.

**Update *(my last try!)*:**

Maybe we can do it now with this solution, we were almost there before.

[image]

Most of what you used, you actually don't need. The thing with the *Curve Tilt* was actually already correct. Only the correct rotation at the beginning was missing.

[image]

> **Note:** To simplify things a bit, I used the math node `To Radians` after the inputs. This way you can easily specify the values in degrees instead of radians.

*(If this fits now, I would still ask you to optimize the question, so that others understand better what you meant. Thanks!)*

[image]

Comment: Great thank you so much for this method. I wonder why you cant just capture the tilt from the original curve and plug it into the set curve tilt? but thank you so much for your solution :D

Comment: @lsw *"I wonder why you cant just capture the tilt from the original curve"* ...This is because there is simply no *Tilt* in the curve before that. Only the tangents of the curve exist, and those are direction vectors, not rotation. I have made an update to illustrate this....

Comment: I see and thank you so much for this explanation

Comment: hi I've noticed a problem when I try to rotate the curves I've kind of solved it but I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong? could you check it out? thank you

Comment: @lsw OK, so slowly it becomes clear what your goal actually is. It would have been good if you had made it clearer from the beginning, then I would have saved myself some work ;-) Anyway, before I change something there again: Why do you actually want to place the node `Realize Instances` BEFORE the node `Curve to Mesh`?

Comment: yep I'm really sorry for the inconvenience I'm making a branch generator and want to place the realise instances before the curve to mesh as I need to use the realise instances node so I can have a set position node which alters the instances as if they are being affected by gravity. I cant have it after because when I go back to capture the radius of my branches it only works with the realise instance node being before the curve to mesh. (ill try to explain with screenshots above)

Comment: @lsw ...sorry, I have to give up. I just don't understand the question. It's just not clear to me what now works the way you want it to, and what of it doesn't. And it's still not clear to me (even after your update) what the end result should be. There are just too many possibilities here for me. It might be good if you outline your goal exactly, and rephrase the question.

Comment: no worrys thanks anyways do you think i should post another question or just re edit this one?

Comment: Or do you want it to look exactly like the end of your video? But then you already have the solution, don't you? (PS: Edit this one, use https://www.deepl.com/)

Comment: yeah I want it to look like the end of the video I'm just really confused about how I accomplished it because I'm doing things like plugging vector math nodes into the float input socket (I'm assuming I've done something wrong)

Comment: thank you so much :)